# Display time calculation in full format

Tags: javascript, html, time, format

I have a small time calculator which subtracts the number of minutes from a 24 hour time e.g. 22 minutes taken from 13:30 equals 13:08, however, instead of displaying "13:08" my webpage displays "13:8" is there anyway to make it display the "13:**0**8"?

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {

function converToMinutes(s) {
    var c = s.split(':');
    return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

function parseTime(s) {
    return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + ":" + parseInt(s) % 60
}


var endTime = document.getElementById("etime").value; 
var startTime = converToMinutes(document.getElementById("stime").value);
var converted = parseTime(startTime - endTime);


document.getElementById('finishtime').innerHTML = converted;

}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Please enter minutes</p>
<input type="text" id="etime">
<br>
<p>Please enter time in 24 hour format (eg. 15:00)</p>
<input type="text" id="stime">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="finishtime">
```

Comment: You want to check if the minutes are less than 10 so you can place a **0** in front of that value.

Comment: `('0'+(parseInt(s) % 60)).slice(-2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + ":" + parseInt(s) % 60;
```

with

```
var seconds = parseInt(s) % 60;
return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + ":" + ((seconds < 10)?"0"+seconds:seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {

function converToMinutes(s) {
    var c = s.split(':');
    return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

function parseTime(s) {
    return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + ":" + parseInt(s) % 60
}
  function parseTime2(s) {
    return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + ":0"+ parseInt(s) % 60
}


var endTime = document.getElementById("etime").value;
  
var startTime = converToMinutes(document.getElementById("stime").value);
 
  var a= (startTime - endTime)%60;
  var converted
  if(a>10){
 converted = parseTime(startTime - endTime);
  }
  else{
  converted = parseTime2(startTime - endTime);
  }


document.getElementById('finishtime').innerHTML = converted;

}
```

```html
<p>Please enter minutes</p>
<input type="text" id="etime">
<br>
<p>Please enter time in 24 hour format (eg. 15:00)</p>
<input type="text" id="stime">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="finishtime">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
 function converToMinutes(s) {
   var c = s.split(':');
   return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
 }
 function parseTime(s) {
   var seconds = parseInt(s) % 60;
  return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + ":" + ((seconds < 10)?"0"+seconds:seconds);
 }
  var endTime = document.getElementById("etime").value; 
 var startTime = converToMinutes(document.getElementById("stime").value);
 var converted = parseTime(startTime - endTime);
 document.getElementById('finishtime').innerHTML = converted;
}
```

```html
<p>Please enter minutes</p>
<input type="text" id="etime" placeholder="Please enter minutes" value="22">
<br>
<p>Please enter time in 24 hour format (eg. 15:00)</p>
<input type="text" id="stime" placeholder="Please enter time formate (eg. 15:00)" value="13:30">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="finishtime"></p>
```